# Evaluating $\;\int\sqrt{2uv}~dv\;?$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do you evaluate $\quad\displaystyle \int\sqrt{2uv}\,dv\;?$

I tried for half an hour using integration of parts and other "methods" but I can't seem to get the answer. I think it's the square root that is confusing me.. as well as the fact that there's a second variable (which I would treat as a constant).

Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't let the extra variable confuse you! Since you are integrating with respect to $v$, don't worry about $u$.

Comment: do you know that $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$?

Comment: You might want to remember, after you've seen DonAntonio's answer, that $\int u^\alpha du=\frac{u^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}+C$ whenever $\alpha\neq -1$.

Comment: Thanks guys- I got the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should treat $u$ as a constant (the "$dv$" tells you to integrate strictly in terms of $v$), so we consider all of $\sqrt{2u}$ to be a "constant."

$$\int\sqrt{2uv}~dv = \quad \int \sqrt{2u}\cdot \sqrt v = \quad \sqrt{2u}\int \sqrt v \,dv = \quad \sqrt{2u}\int v^{1/2} dv$$

Can you take it from here?

Remember the rule for integrating with respect to a variable raised to a power:

$$\int v^a \,dv = \dfrac{v^{a + 1}}{a+1} + \;\text{Constant}\quad \text{if} \;\;a\neq -1$$

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, Sue!

Comment: @amWhy: Very nice my dear friend. :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\sqrt{2uv}dv=\sqrt2u\int v^{1/2}dv=\sqrt{2u}\frac{v^{3/2}}{3/2}+K\ldots$$